# How to send emojis from bot to user in Microsoft teams

Tags: c#, botframework, emoji, microsoft-teams

I created a bot in the MS bot framework and linked it to the Teams channel. How to send emoji from bot to users?

Teams support UTF-16, I have tried await `stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("\U0001F600");` to send the emoji as a response from bot to the user, but it is not in the format of the emoji which is available in teams.

`stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("\U0001F600");` it shows  when I actually want is (smile) from teams which is slightly bigger and animated.

The emoji in teams are stored in the form of URL: "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/evergreen-assets/skype/v2/smile/50.png"

Comment: @Mohit Verma's answer is correct. You can refer to https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html  & https://emojipedia.org/slightly-smiling-face/for getting the exact type of custom smiling face emoji. Note that it depends on the OS you are using and appears different on different OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the emojis have their textual code. For example: :) :P :D
When you want to send a smiley append “:)” into the text and it will automatically render it as smiley in the chat box.

Also for every single recipient device , code could be rendered in a different manner, you can check the complete list here:

https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/full-emoji-list.html#1f642

I would suggest you to use 1f642 code for slightly smiling face.

See if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows and Visual Studio, you can simply press "**window key + .**" and you will get a window with emojis that you can simply add to your text.

[image]

[image]
Or you can also copy any emoji and paste it in your text. Check [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/)

Comment: Thanks, Didn't see the period **.** at first, so `Win +` kept getting the magnifier.